# Java's alternative to a C# finding text in a page using particular tag

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am struggling with a piece of code in C# that I am not sure how to change to Java:

This is the calling method:

```
Assert.Istrue(DashboardPage.IsAt, "Failed to login);"
```

This is the Dashboard class with the functionality. This is the C# that I want to convert to Java:

```
public class DashboardPage {

    public static bool isAt {
        get {
            var h2 = Driver.driver().FindElements(By.TagName("h2"));
            if (h2.Count>0)
                return h2[0].Text =="Dashboard";
            return false;
        }
    }           
}
```

---

Because I was not able to create the above functionality in Java, I did an alternative as below.But as you can see this checks the whole page source and not for particular tag.

```
public static boolean isTextPresent(String text) {
    try {
        boolean b = Driver.driver().getPageSource().contains(text);
        return b;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code should be somewhat like this:

```
public static boolean isTextPresent(WebDriver driver,String text){
try{
    boolean b = driver.findElement(By.tagName("h2")).getText().contains(text);
    return b;
}
catch(Exception e){
    return false;
}
}
```

Above example will find the first available h2 tag in the DOM.
If you want check your text across all h2 tags, you should use `findElements()`:

```
List<WebElement> tags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("h2"));
for(WebElement e:tags){
    if(e.getText().contains(text))
    return true;
}
```

Note that, here I'm passing WebDriver as an additional argument and assuming that you have declared and defined WebDriver already in the class from which you are calling (something like `WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver()`). This will allow the function to use the same instance.

Also, I have used `contains()` here , this will check the substring. If you want the exact match use `equals()` instead.